# Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration not recognized even after installing as admin

Tags: powershell, email, exchange-server

I am trying to use the `Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration` cmdlet to configure an Exchange mailbox auto reply in a script.  I used the command `Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement` in an elevated powershell prompt and was able to confirm that it is installed using `Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement; Get-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement`. I still get the error message " The term 'Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet..." on both the shell and my script, even after including `Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement`.

I appreciate any guidance on getting this cmdlet to work.

Comment: You'll want to call [`Connect-ExchangeOnline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/connect-exchangeonline?view=exchange-ps) immediately after importing the module, before any other exchange commands - it'll establish a remote session with ExchangeOnline and import the relevant commands from the remote session back into your local shell

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to call Connect-ExchangeOnline immediately after importing the module.  Thank you Mathias.

Comment: You're most welcome, don't forget to accept your own answer :)